# If an HTML field has a class and a name, but no ID, then what JQuery code can make it a required field?

Tags: jquery

How to make this field a required field?

```
<input class="wpf-tags" name="topic[tags]">
```

I have tried this line of code and it did not work.

```
$("topic[tags]").prop('required',true);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try 1 should be: `$("#wpf_tags_5f790c10849e0").prop('required',true);`, while Try 2 should be `$("[name='topic[tags]']").prop('required',true);`

Answer (score 2):

Class should be proceeded by a dot so try

```
$('input.wpf-tags').prop('required',true);
```

Edit: to ensure its the input with this specific name, you could do `$('input[name="topic[tags]"]').prop('required', true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [select based on an attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors), you would use the selector `[attributeName="attributeValue"]`.  So, if you want to use your input name, you need to do something like this:

```
$('input[name="topic[tags]"]')
```